# Is it possible to add my own custom language in Minecraft on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, minecraft

I have created my own language, and I wanted to add it to minecraft, but I can't seem to find anything on google about doing so, I'm on Ubuntu. Is it possible to add my language into minecraft?

Comment: What do you mean by "language"?

Comment: a full language. I wanted to add it to minecraft to see if it would sound right in a more natural setting than what I can manage.

Comment: You mean a localization file?

Comment: Sure? I don't know what a localization file is.

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265102/where-are-minecraft-languages-stored-and-how-can-i-add-a-new-one). [Information about localization](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/internationalization/). "Lang file" -> "file used for localization."

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom Language with a Resourcepack. [I had made a example](https://mega.nz/#!idNj1K5A!TqNhBIW4ucFeM-I2R_NllrwCdruhndo7biP-rXnyicQ). Just edit the two files inside the resourcepack. Your language only appears in the languagemenu if you select the resourcepack.